# Error: Failed to serialize user into session (Node JS, Passport JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm getting an error while trying to use `Passport.JS` to login/register users with their Google account.
Here's the code:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const keys = require('./keys');
const User = require('../models/user');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(foundUser => done(null, foundUser))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
    clientID: keys.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, userInfo, done) => {
    User.find({
        googleId: userInfo.id
      }).then(foundUser => {
        if (!foundUser) {
          new User({
              userName: userInfo.displayName,
              googleId: userInfo.id
            })
            .save().then((createdUser) => done(null, createdUser))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } else {
          done(null, foundUser);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })
);
```

The error I'm getting is this: **Error: Failed to serialize user into session**.